# How to make the window size the same as the image opened in C++/Cinder

Tags: c++, cinder

I made a program with cinder/c++ (I am using Xcode) that allows you to open an image and show it in a window. I was wondering how can I make the size of the window the same as the size of the picture that had been opened?

Here is my code:

```
#include "cinder/app/AppNative.h"
#include "cinder/gl/Texture.h"
#include "cinder/Text.h"
#include "cinder/ImageIo.h"

using namespace ci;
using namespace ci::app;
using namespace std;

class ConvexSpiralApp : public AppNative {
  public:
    void setup();
    void draw();

    gl::Texture myImage;
};

void ConvexSpiralApp::setup()
{
    try
    {
        ci::fs::path p = getOpenFilePath( "", ImageIo::getLoadExtensions());

        if( ! p.empty() )
        { // an empty string means the user canceled
            myImage = gl::Texture( loadImage( p ) );
        }
    }

    catch( ... )
    {
        console() << "Unable to load the image." << std::endl;
    }
}

void ConvexSpiralApp::draw()
{
    // clear out the window with black
    gl::clear( Color( 0, 0, 0 ) );

    gl::draw( myImage, getWindowBounds() );
}

CINDER_APP_NATIVE( ConvexSpiralApp, RendererGl )
```

Gale

Answer (score 0):

I did it!

```
myImage = gl::Texture( processedImage );

setWindowSize(myImage.getWidth(), myImage.getWidth() );
```

Comment: *setWindowSize(myImage.getWidth(), myImage.getHeight() );